# How to convert Afex or car ANOVA models to lmer? Observed variables

Tags: r, lme4, anova, xtable

In the `afex` package we can find this example of ANOVA analysis:

```
data(obk.long, package = "afex")
# estimate mixed ANOVA on the full design:
# can be written in any of these ways: 

aov_car(value ~ treatment * gender + Error(id/(phase*hour)), data = obk.long,
        observed = "gender")

aov_4(value ~ treatment * gender + (phase*hour|id), data = obk.long,
        observed = "gender")

aov_ez("id", "value", obk.long, between = c("treatment", "gender"), 
       within = c("phase", "hour"), observed = "gender")
```

My question is, How can I write the same model in `lme4`?
In particular, I don't know how to include the "observed" term?

If I just write

```
lmer(value ~ treatment * gender + (phase*hour|id), data = obk.long,
     observed = "gender")
```

I get an error telling that observed is not a valid option.

Furthermore, if I just remove the observed option `lmer` produces the error:

> Error: number of observations (=240) <= number of random effects (=240) for term (phase * hour | id); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable.

Where in the lmer syntax do I specify the "between" or "within" variable?.  As far as I know you just write the dependent variable on the left side and all other variables on the right side, and the error term as (1|id).

The package "car" uses the idata for the intra-subject variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might not know enough about classical ANOVA theory to answer this question completely, but I'll take a crack. First, a couple of points:

- the `observed` argument appears only to be relevant for the computation of effect size.

> observed: ‘character’ vector indicating which of the variables are
>             observed (i.e, measured) as compared to experimentally
>             manipulated. The default effect size reported (generalized
>             eta-squared) requires correct specification of the obsered [sic]
>             (in contrast to manipulated) variables.

... so I think you'd be safe leaving it out.

- if you want to override the error you can use

```
  control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore")
```

... but this probably isn't the right way forward.

I **think** but am not sure that this is the right way:

```
m1 <- lmer(value ~ treatment * gender + (1|id/phase:hour), data = obk.long,
    control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore",
                            check.nobs.vs.nlev="ignore"),
    contrasts=list(treatment=contr.sum,gender=contr.sum))
```

This specifies that the interaction of `phase` and `hour` varies within `id`. The residual variance and (phase by hour within id) variance are confounded (which is why we need the overriding `lmerControl()` specification), so don't trust those particular variance estimates.  However, the main effects of treatment and gender should be handled just the same.  If you load `lmerTest` instead of `lmer` and run `summary(m1)` or `anova(m1)` it gives you the same degrees of freedom (10) for the fixed (gender and treatment) effects that are computed by `afex`.

`lme` gives comparable answers, but needs to have the phase-by-hour interaction constructed beforehand:

```
library(nlme)
obk.long$ph <- with(obk.long,interaction(phase,hour))
m2 <- lme(value ~ treatment * gender,
             random=~1|id/ph, data = obk.long,
    contrasts=list(treatment=contr.sum,gender=contr.sum))
anova(m2,type="marginal")
```

I don't know how to reconstruct `afex`'s tests of the random effects.

Answer (score 4):

As Ben Bolker correctly says, simply leave `observed` out.

Furthermore, I would not recommend to do what you want to do. Using a mixed model for a data set without replications within each cell of the design per participant is somewhat questionable as it is not really clear how to specify the random effects structure. Importantly, the Barr et al. maxim of "keep it maximal" does not work here as you realized. The problem is that the model is overparametrized (hence the error from `lmer`).

I recommend using the ANOVA. More discussion on exactly this question can be found on a crossvalidated thread where Ben and me [discussed this more thoroughly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/130714/442).

Comment: you might want to point out that you're the author of `afex` (and hence something of an authority on the subject :-) )

Comment: Yes, I know, I only use random effects when I have replication for each individual.
I was just asking in general.

Comment: @BenBolker Perhaps true. But then it always feels a little like bragging. And for most questions revolving around `lme4` you are usually the greater authority.

Comment: in this case I would argue it's actually useful information for the OP